# Read x number of bytes from a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

Is there a way to read a certain number of bytes from a RandomAccessFile in Java?

Comment: What did you find when you read the javadoc or used code completion in your IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `read(byte[] b)` method? From the Java docs..

> Reads up to b.length bytes of data from this file into an array of
>   bytes. This method blocks until at least one byte of input is
>   available.